# How do i loop through object and remove properties which are not equal to something

Tags: javascript

Below code removes hours and days properties.What I am trying to do is remove properties which are not equal to hours and days.How do I iterate properties and check if it's not equal then remove?

```
Object.keys(allcoursetimeobject).forEach(function(key) {
      //this removes hours and days.I want to remove properties which are not equal to hours and days.

       delete allcoursetimeobject[key].hours;
       delete allcoursetimeobject[key].days;


    });
```

Comment: Add more details to this question. It's ambiguous.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just repeat the loop

```
allcoursetimeobject = {
  test1 : {
    hours : 3,
    days : 4,
    something : 3,
  },
  test2 : {
    hours : 3,
    days : 4,
    somethingElse : 5,
  }
}

Object.keys(allcoursetimeobject).forEach(function(key) {
  Object.keys(allcoursetimeobject[key]).forEach(function(secondKey){
    if(allcoursetimeobject[key][secondKey] !== allcoursetimeobject[key].hours && allcoursetimeobject[key][secondKey] !== allcoursetimeobject[key].days){
      delete allcoursetimeobject[key][secondKey];
    }
  });
});
console.log(allcoursetimeobject);
```

[demo](https://jsfiddle.net/5h6whynv/9/)

Answer (score 0):

## Assumptions:

> You want to delete properties from objects within the allcoursetimeobject, based on the code snippet provided by you.

**Then answer is:**

```js
var allcoursetimeobject = {
  a: {
   hours: 10,
    days: 20,
    test: "Delete This"
  },
  b: {
   hours: 5,
    days: 15,
    test: "Delete This"
  }
};

Object.keys(allcoursetimeobject).forEach(function(key) {
  Object.keys(allcoursetimeobject[key]).forEach(function(k) {
    if (k != "hours" && k != "days") {
      delete allcoursetimeobject[key][k];
    }
  });
});

console.log(allcoursetimeobject);
```

> Or Maybe, you want to delete properties in the allcoursetimeobject object itself

**Then:**

```js
var allcoursetimeobject = {
 hours: 10,
  days: 20,
  test: "Delete This"
};

Object.keys(allcoursetimeobject).forEach(function(key) {
  if (key != "hours" && key != "days") {
    delete allcoursetimeobject[key];
  }
});

console.log(allcoursetimeobject);
```

> Hope that helps!

Comment: includes() method in arrays is awesome, but sadly has no IE support.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Object.keys()` to iterate through keys of an object and then using `array#includes` you can check if a key exists in a given array. If found, delete it using `delete`.

```js
const oldObject = { key1: { hours: 3, days: 4, prop1: 3, }, key2: { hours: 3, days: 4, prop2: 5, } };
Object.keys(oldObject).forEach(k => {
  Object.keys(oldObject[k]).forEach(key => {
    if(['hours','days'].includes(key)){
      delete oldObject[k][key];
    }
  });
});
console.log(oldObject);
```